# can't assign to function call Error-Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, barcode

I'm working on a project to create a postal bar code out of an inputted 5 digit zipcode. When I run the code, I get an error that says "can't assign to function call". What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

```
zipcode = input("What is your 5 digit zipcode?")
s = zipcode.split(",")

def barcode(a):                                                        
    if a==0:
        print("||:::") 
    elif a==1:
        print(":::||")
    elif a==2:
        print("::|:|")
    elif a==3:
        print("::||:")
    elif a==4:
        print(":|::|")
    elif a==5:
        print(":|:|:")
    elif a==6:
        print(":||::")
    elif a==7:
        print("|:::|")
    elif a==8:
        print("|::|:")
    elif a==9:
        print("|:|::")

for barcode(a) in s:
    print(barcode(a))
```

Comment: I would suggest changing `total=int(zipcode[0])...` to `total=sum(int(x) for x in zipcode)`. Much more readable and way easier for you to type.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
for barcode(a) in s:
```

It's invalid syntax because the name bound in a for loop has to be a python identifier.

You were probably trying for something like this instead:

```
for the_zipcode in s:
    print(barcode(the_zipcode))
```

Comment: print(the_zipcode(barcode))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: So i changed what you suggested and its giving me this^

Comment: I see now ha, sorry, BUT Im trying to call the function "barcode(a)" in the for loop to print the "::|:|:" things per digit in the inputted zipcode... when I use "the_zipcode" it just prints the zipcode inputted

Comment: You are god of python please help... I will sacrifice my firstborn to your mightiness...

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain your problem is your use of `s=zipcode.split(",")`. What that does is split the string that is put in by the user (if you're using python 3) into an array of strings, where each element is delimited by a comma. For example:

```
'11111'.split(',') # ['11111']
'11111,12345'.split(',') # ['11111', '12345']
```

That is almost certainly not what you want, since you're asking the user to input a 5-digit zip code. If you just use the input directly, I think you'll get what you want.

That is:

```
zipcode=input("What is your 5 digit zipcode?")
# . . .
for digit in zipcode:
  print(barcode(digit))
```